# When should I use worker-threads?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am currently working on a backend which provides rest endpoints for my frontend with nestjs. In some endpoints I receive e.g. an array of elements which I need to process.

Concrete Example:
I receive an array of 50 elements. For each element I need to make a SQL request. Therefore I need to loop over the array and do stuff in SQL.

I always ask myself: At what amount of elements should I use for example worker threads to not block the event loop?

Maybe I misunderstood the blocking of the event loop and someone can enlight me.

Comment: SQL queries already don't block the event loop, so that would not be a good example for using worker threads. One example would be using them to increase the throughput of your server responses by delegating each entire HTTP request to separate threads using some sort of distribution strategy like round-robin.

Comment: Using worker threads for the example you have shown would most certainly be slower, even if that loop were 1000's.  I would even say using for entire Http requests like mentioned by @PatrickRoberts is debatatable as that would negate aggressive caching schemes you could use.  A better example might be were you did some fancy image processing, maybe like some AI upscaling etc, a worker thread would really help here.

Comment: @Keith higher throughput =/= faster. In fact the cost of parallelism is often higher latency. So yes it's slower, but because it can block multiple event loops handling multiple requests in parallel, it will be able to offer higher throughput than a single-threaded server. Also I'd argue against implementing caching in Node.js. That's what proxy servers are for.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  A Proxy server is for proxying HTTP requests.  Let's take a very simple example, lets say you have some static data stored on your SQL server, and every request requires access to this.  By not using caching in node this DB query will now need doing for all requests.  It really is one of the biggest benefits of Node, say compared to PHP were things like MemCached have to be used, and that's way slower than internal caching inside node.  If you did want to cluster, personally I would go for Sticky Session's rather than round robbin.

Comment: if your request is taking like 5-10+ minutes then you should implement an async search with `start`, `check`, `getresults` apis. maybe using worker of another service.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that you'll need worker-threads in this scenario. As long as the sql-queries are executed asynchronsouly, i.e. the sql-query calls do *not* block, you will be fine. You can use `Promise.all` to speed up the processing of the loop, as the queries will be executed in parallel, e.g.

```
const dbQueryPromises = [];

for(const entry of data) {
   dbQueryPromises.push(dbConnection.query(buildQuery(entry)));
}

await Promise.all(dbQueryPromises);
```

If, however, your code performs computation-heavy operations inside the loop, then you should consider worker-threads as the long running operations on your call stack will block the eventloop.

Answer (score 0):

Only use them if you need to do CPU-intensive tasks with large amounts of data. They allow you to avoid the serialization step of the data. 50 Is not enough I believe